# Is there a proper design pattern for this situation?

Tags: python, django, api, design-patterns

I'm building a simple crud app in Django which is basically enhanced reporting for commerce related software. So I pull information on behalf of a user from another software's API, do a bunch of aggregation/calculations on the data, and then display a report to the user.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make this all happen quickly. While I'm certain there are optimizations that can be made in my Python code, I'd like to find some way to be able to make multiple calculations on reasonably large sets of objects without making the user wait like 10 seconds.

The problem is that the data can change in a given moment. If the user makes changes to their data in the other software, there is no way for me to know that without hitting the API again for that info. So I don't see a way that I can cache information or pre-fetch it without making a ridiculous number of requests to the API.

In a perfect world the API would have webhooks I could use to watch for data changes but that's not an option.

Is my best bet to just optimize the factors I control to the best of my ability and hope my users can live with it?

Comment: Can you add third party API link and the endpoints you want to consume ?

Comment: Does your report sources are the commerce rest api + another rest api ? Or is a mix of some sql + rest api data? Is your main requirement just to decrease  the 10 seconds? Could your user understand that some calculations takes long like monthly bank calculations, accounting month-end close, get all country citizens weight average, etc?

Comment: You have explained the options, all what left for us is to give our opinion. But opinion based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The design pattern that could help here is Observer, but you can't use that unless webhooks or a similar callback mechanism is provided.